# JGitFlow maven plugin release-start from custom branch

Tags: maven, release, jgit, jgitflow-maven-plugin

Is it possible to make a release from custom branch (not `develop`)?

I tried to use `startCommit` command, but Maven JGitFlow plugin has been switched to the `develop` branch before release is started.

Also, when I changed git configuration manually, it was automatically changed to `develop`.

I would like to use following steps:

1. `release-start` - create release branch
2. `release-finish` - create tag, merge to the master and develop, update `pom.xml` versions.
3. Issue found
4. Create a branch from tagged version
5. Fix issues there
6. Make another release from that branch

Comment: Did you try setting the flowInitContext property? I think that allows you to override the default branch names: develop, master, etc...

Comment: @whomer Thanks for the answer. Currently we decide to try to change our current flow or to use different plugin, since our current flow does not match JGitFlow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the parameter `startCommit` (http://jgitflow.bitbucket.org/release-start-mojo.html#startCommit) is not enough because that provokes an exception with m5.1 (https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/MJF-284). Using `flowInitContext` seems to work though (http://jgitflow.bitbucket.org/release-start-mojo.html#flowInitContext). You just have to adjust the develop branch (source branch for release branches) to point to your custom branch.

The only thing which cannot be achieved that way, is that during `release-finish` a merge back to the global develop branch is done. Usually you also don't want to merge back to master (since that may provoke git merge conflicts), which need to be resolved manually.